# JTextField uneditable in JWindow

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield

I have a Jwindow, and when I added a Jtextfield to it, the textfield became uneditable.

```
JWindow window = new JWindow();
window.setBounds(400, 100, 700,500);
window.setVisible(true);
window.setLayout(null);
JTextField text = new JTextField();
text.setBounds(300, 300, 150, 30);
text.setEditable(true);       
window.getContentPane().add(text);
```

But when I tried to use Jframe as Jwindow's owner, the textfield was now editable, but the frame showed up together with the jwindow :

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
frame.setVisible(true);
JWindow window = new JWindow();
window.setBounds(400, 100, 700,500);
window.setVisible(true);
window.setLayout(null);
JTextField text = new JTextField();
text.setBounds(300, 300, 150, 30);
text.setEditable(true);       
window.getContentPane().add(text);
```

So, I have 2 questions :

1. Why JTextField is uneditable in JWindow and how could I make it editable?
2. What is the main purpose of using JFrame as JWindow's border?

Comment: Take a look here http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t366288-jtextfield-inactive-in-a-jwindow.html

Comment: The problem is that when i used jframe, then both the jwindow and jframe appeared at the same time..

Comment: Are you sure you read the complete solution provided in that link.

Comment: Yeah, im sure (with Andrew's code in ur link)

Comment: unrelated to your problem: _do not_ locate/size components manually, that's the job of a LayoutManager

Comment: for 1) no. Read the api doc as well: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#isFocusableWindow. But: what is your goal? Why do you want a _window_ (as opposed to an undecorated dialog) that doesn't appear in the taskbar?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

EDIT,

- contents of `JWindow` is accesible only if its parent is displayed on the screen
- for editable and accesible contents use un_decorated `JDialog` instead of `JWindow`, jDialog doesn't caused non_accesible contents,
- reason why ..., I can't explain, not undestand why, no way in this moment, the API says me nothing about caused accesible, editable ...

.
.
.

```
1. Why JTextField is uneditable in JWindow and how could i let it able to edit?
```

really don't know

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class WindowTest {

    private JFrame frame;

    public JPanel createContentPane() {
        JTextField text = new JTextField("Whatewer");        
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.add(text);
        createAndShowWindow();
        return panel;
    }

    void createAndShowGUI() {
        frame = new JFrame("Window Test");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setContentPane(createContentPane());
        frame.setLocation(50, 50);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private void createAndShowWindow() {
        JTextField text = new JTextField("Whatewer");
        JWindow win = new JWindow(frame);
        win.setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 1));
        win.add(text);
        win.pack();
        win.setLocation(150, 50);
        win.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {
                new WindowTest().createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

EDIT

```
Yes, both are editable, and i wannt only JWindow to be displayed. Thanks!!
```

- by default JWindow required JFrame for correct workaround
- nobody tell that this JFrame must be visible (valid for GUI), then remove these code lines from `frame.setDefaultClose`.... including `frame.setVisible(true);` from my example
- in this form current JVM instance never gone from RAM, untill your PC restarted or swith off, you have to add separated exit `JButton` with code line `System.exit(0)` inside `ActionListener`

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't work on my machine, in the sense that it didn't  let the JWindow appear without the JFrame.

Comment: @Fff Dgg no idea what and why something doesn't works on your machine, there must be another issue hidden you your code, I'm assuning that my code example works,

Comment: This is your code's output on my machine, pzl have a look : http://flic.kr/p/bCpojk

Comment: @Fff Dgg right agreed, my question are 1) both JTextField are accesible and editable isn't it ??? 2) do you want to display only JWindow ???, 3) is/are there another issue(s)

Comment: Yes, both are editable, and i wannt only JWindow to be displayed. Thanks!!

Comment: When i deleted codes from : frame.setDefaultClose.. to frame.setVisible(true) >> there's nothing appeared. Only deleted the last code frame.setVisible(true) >> the jframe disappeared, but again the JWindow is uneditable.. Im using java 1.6..

Comment: _really don't know_ reading the api doc helps :-) http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#isFocusableWindow clearly states that the second bullet of your edit is wrong

Comment: @kleopatra this code caused non_editable JTextField for me too

Comment: @Fff Dgg no way, true is that I never used alone JWindow, for the rest see my edit here

Answer (score 3):

The JWindow should be focusable. Use `public void setFocusable(boolean focusable)` method.